# How to multiply a function with an integral

Tags: calculus

How can I multiply the $e^{-\int_{0}^{x}b(\tau)d\tau}$ with $\int_{0}^{x} f(x,y)e^{-\int_{0}^{y}b(\tau)d\tau}dy$ ?

Comment: In the same way as you multiply any two things. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?$$\begin{align}e^{-\int_0^x b(\tau) \ d\tau} \int_0^x f(x,y)\ e^{-\int_0^y b(\tau) \ d \tau}\ dy&=\int_0^x f(x,y)\ e^{-\int_0^x b(\tau) \ d\tau} \ e^{-\int_0^y b(\tau) \ d \tau}\ dy \\ &=\int_0^x f(x,y)\  e^{-\int_0^x b(\tau) \ d\tau-\int_0^y b(\tau) \ d \tau}\ dy \end{align}$$

Note that $e^{-\int_0^x b(\tau) d\tau}$ is independent of $y$ and so you can apply $c(x) \int f(y) \ dy=\int c(x)\ f(y) \ dy$.